# How do I fix a verification token error on slack channel for azure bot services?

Tags: azure, botframework, slack, azure-bot-service

I created a simple bot that I wanted to test channel integrations on and it worked properly in the Web Chat and in the Facebook Messenger integration. However when I followed the steps outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), I keep getting an error in the Issues column of the Slack bot that says: `Verification token mismatch. Please check your bot's Slack configuration and make sure the verification token is correct.`

[Azure error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddGrn.png)

[The fields I used for setting up the azure service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcQG9.png)

I have tried regenerating the verification token several times and I still get the same error. I have also restarted my local bot, restarted ngrok, and changed the endpoint to the new ngrok address.

Comment: This may be an error on the Slack side. A couple things to check: Are you certain you put in Slack's Client Secret and not the Signing Secret for the Slack Channel Client Secret value? This part I'm doubtful on, but have you checked the Redirect URL under OAuth & Permissions or the Request URL under Event Subscriptions? Lastly, have you simply tried starting over with a new Slack app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using signed secrets functionality instead of token verification. See:

https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#how_do_commands_work

"This is a verification token, a deprecated feature that you shouldn't use any more. It was used to verify that requests were legitimately being sent by Slack to your app, but you should use the signed secrets functionality to do this instead."

Comment: I tried replacing the verification token with the signed secret, however it seems as though it is a known issue that it can't currently use signed secrets? https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+slack